# Can I use tabs in a sql file run at OracleDB?

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, oracle10g, oracle11g

Ive got Following code:

```
CONSTRAINT PK_I_TBOWXXX PRIMARY KEY(I_RID) USING INDEX TABLESPACE Index_Data,
CONSTRAINT UK_I_TBOWXXX UNIQUE(I_CID, ID) USING INDEX TABLESPACE Index_Data
```

and i want it to fomat like this:

```
CONSTRAINT PK_I_TBOWXXX          PRIMARY KEY (I_RID)            USING INDEX TABLESPACE Index_Data,
CONSTRAINT UK_I_TBOWXXX          UNIQUE      (I_CID, ID)        USING INDEX TABLESPACE Index_Data
```

can I use tabs for this without worrying about errors?

Or should i use spaces / should i just keep it like that?
It should work on **10g and 11g**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abosultely.

oracle ignores all the additional spaces/tabs, so you can work on making your code look as neat as you want it to. :)

```
create table oats.testcreate
(
id number,
name varchar2(20)
);
```

Will work just just the same as..

```
create table    oats.testcreate
(
id      number,
name            varchar2(20)
);
```

Although only one of them looks like the code you can understand :)